# How to parse the csv file without two blank fields in awk?

Tags: csv, awk

The csv structure is such a way as below.

```
"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",
```

Ther are four fields in the csv file.
the first : field1
the second : field2
the third  : field3,with,commas
the forth : field4

Here is my regular expression for awk.

```
 '^"|","|",$' 

debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print NF}'
6
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $1}'

debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $2}'
field1
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $3}'
field2
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $4}'
field3,with,commas
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $5}'
field4
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F '^"|","|",$' '{print $6}'
```

Two issues remains in my regular expression **'^"|","|",$'**.

1.4 fiels to be parsed as 6 fields by **'^"|","|",$'**.
2.$1 and $6 was parsed into blank.

How to write a regular expression  **format** to make:

```
echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F format '{print NF}'
4
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F  format '{print $1}'
field1
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F format '{print $2}'
field2
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F foramt '{print $3}'
field3,with,commas
debian8@hwy:~$ echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' |awk -F format '{print $4}'
field4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround could be to set `FS` to `","` and remove using `gsub` the character at the start and the end of each record:

```
echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' | awk -v FS='","' '{gsub(/^"|",$/, ""); print NF, $1, $2, $3, $4}'
4 field1 field2 field3,with,commas field4
```

Comment: echo '"field1","field2","field3,with,commas","field4",' | awk -F '","' '{gsub(/^"|",$/, ""); print NF, $1, $2, $3, $4}'
4 field1 field2 field3,with,commas field4

Comment: To make it more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `FPAT` variable is probably what you want. Take a look at the documentation and examples [in the Users Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)